# Node.js & Gulp: Порядок вызова '.pipe()'s не совпадает с описанной в коде последовательностью

Tags: node.js, gulp, typescript

В приведённом ниже коде (описание gulp-таска), функция `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass()` вызывается после выполнения `console.log('intercepted!');`. Естественно, при такой неожиданной последовательности, в `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass(targetFileAbsolutePath)` параметр `targetFileAbsolutePath` ещё не инициализирован, потому имеет значение`undefined`.

```js
let currentSourceFileAbsolutePath;

return gulp.src(entryPointsSourceFilesPathsOrGlobs)

    // "gulpPlugins.intercept" - это "gulp-intercept"
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.intercept( sourceVynilFile => {
      console.log('intercepted!');
      currentSourceFileAbsolutePath = sourceVynilFile.path;
      console.log(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath); // Пока всё нормально
      return sourceVynilFile;
    }))

    // "gulpPlugins.if" - это "gulp-if"
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.if(
        // currentSourceFileAbsolutePath имеет значение undefined !!!
        fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath),
        gulpPlugins.sass()
    ));

// ...

fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass(targetFileAbsolutePath) {

    console.warn('---');
    console.warn(targetFileAbsolutePath); // undefined!

    const targetFilenameExtension = Path.extname(targetFileAbsolutePath);
    let targetFilenameExtensionIsSupportedBySassPreprocessor = false;

    for (const filenameExtension of SUPPORTED_FILENAME_EXTENSIONS__SASS_PREPROCESSOR) {
      if (filenameExtension === targetFilenameExtension) {
        targetFilenameExtensionIsSupportedBySassPreprocessor = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    return targetFilenameExtensionIsSupportedBySassPreprocessor;
}
```

Исходный код, вообще-то говоря, на TypeScript-е с самыми строгими настройками, но я его переписал на JavaScript для данного вопроса, чтобы больше людей смогли понять код. Упомянул я TypeScript затем, что компилятор каким-то образом понял, что в `pipe(gulpPlugins.if(/*...*/))` параметр ещё не проинициализирован, а потому отработал с ошибкой.

Я очень удивился этому потому, что у меня есть другой похожий gulp-таск, где всё работает нормально:

```
let currentSourceFileAbsolutePath: string;

return gulp.src(entryPointsSourceFilesPathsOrGlobs)

    .pipe(gulpPlugins.intercept(sourceVynilFile => {
      currentSourceFileAbsolutePath = sourceVynilFile.path;
      return sourceFile;
    }))

    .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.intercept(compiledHtmlFile => {
      // currentSourceFileAbsolutePath проинициализирован, всё нормально.
      if (shouldValidateCompiledHtmlRespectiveToSourceFile(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath)) {
        HtmlValidator.validateHtml(compiledHtmlFile);
      }
      return compiledHtmlFile;
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(() => (
      // currentSourceFileAbsolutePath проинициализирован, всё нормально.
      getOutputDirectoryForPreprocessedMarkupEntryPointFileByRespectiveSourceFile(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath)
    )));
```

Что я упустил? Был какой-то асинхронный вызов?

---

### А зачем, собственно, такой сложный код? Что за задача?

Логика в реальном проекте естественно, гораздо сложнее (ввиду объёмного ТЗ), и если не вдаваться в детали, то нужно просто внутри каждого `pipe()` знать абсолютный путь *к исходному* файлу. Как только файл пройдёт, например, `pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())`, расширение сменится с `.pug` на `.html`, и это уже будет НЕ исходный файл.

Разные решения принимать гораздо легче зная путь именно к исходному файлу, потому с ним связана конкретная конфигурация, которую надо найти и на её основе уже что-то сделать с файлом. Если путь к файлу изменился, то тогда подходящую конфигурацию будет найти гораздо сложнее, а восстановление пути к исходному файлу по модифицированному (например восстановить `path/to/file/test.pug` по `path/to/file/test.html`) очень сильно утяжелит код, потому что:

- В　зависимости от конкретного таска алгоритм восстановления пути будет отличаться
- По мере прохождения через `.pipe`, путь к файлу может меняться неоднократно
- Код постоянно модифицируется, и по мере его модфикации придётся менять и алгоритмы восстановления исходного пути.

Поэтому зачада, ради которой в вопросе присуствует такой пепривычный для gulp-тасков код - это знать путь к исходному файлу в каждом `pipe()`. Если есть какой-то более простой способ это сделать - буду рад его увидеть в Ваших замечательных ответах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вариант использования плагина [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) синхронный - он отрабатывает один раз во время инициализации обработчиков потоков.

Функция `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass()` вызывается один раз *ДО* чтения данных из потока,  получает непроинициализированный аргумент `currentSourceFileAbsolutePath` для своего параметра и возвращает результат == `false`. Плагин *gulp-if* видит, что первый его аргумент имеет тип `boolean` - возвращает, согласно значению первого аргумента, объект из своих true/false-аргументов. Полученный таким образом объект, будет использоваться при чтении данных из потока для *ВСЕХ* файлов.

Для того, чтобы поменять ситуацию и сделать так, чтобы плагин *gulp-if* срабатывал при чтении данных из потока для каждого файла - нужно агрумент для `pipe()` указать так:

```
...

// "gulpPlugins.if" - это "gulp-if"
.pipe(gulpPlugins.if(
    fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass,
    gulpPlugins.sass()
));

...
```

Тогда плагин *gulp-if* вернет объект [ternaryStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ternary-stream), проициализировав его своими аргументами, а функция `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass` будет вызываться во время чтения данных из потока для *КАЖДОГО* файла и аргументом для нее будут данные из предшествующего `pipe()`.

И переменная `currentSourceFileAbsolutePath` будет 
корректно проинициализирована предшествующими обработчиками на момент вызовов ф-ии  `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass()`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! И за Ваше время, которое Вы потратили на чтение вопроса.